# is this correct that if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0$ then $f$ is independent from $y$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose that $A=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 : x> 0 $ or $ y=0 \}$ and $f:A\to \Bbb R$ is an arbitary function. Prove that

1. If $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=0$ then $f$ is independent from $x$
2. If $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}= 0$ then $f$ is constant
3. If $f$ be constant from variable $x$ then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=0$

And is this correct that if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0$  then $f$ is independent from $y$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(x, y)$ is differentiable with respect to $y$ in every point of $A$, then it is true.

For example, if $f(x) = \arctan (x) + \arctan (1/x)$, you can check that $f'(x) = 0$ *but* $f(x)$ is not differentiable for $x = 0$ (is not even defined there)

And in fact $f(x)$ depends on $x$; we have $$f(x) = \begin{cases} \pi/2, & \text{if $x > 0$} \\ -\pi/2 & \text{if $x < 0$} \end{cases}$$

If you restrict the interval you are considering to (say) $I = (0, 1)$ then it is true that $f'(x) = 0$ for all $x \in I$ and in fact $f(x)$ is constant there.

The usual way to prove this is to use the mean value theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, by definition, we have
$$ \frac{ \partial f}{\partial x} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ f(x+h,y) - f(x,y) }{h} =0$$
for all $x,y$. What can we deduce?